# How to add driver to dkms?

Tags: drivers, kernel, updates, dkms

I want wi-fi driver (bcmwl) automaticly included into kernel after each update. Now I need to reinstall package bcmwl after each kernel update. Without it driver isn't loaded. How to configure this driver in dkms to be automaticly included into kernel?

When I reinstall driver I see in terminal:

```
Building only for 3.13.0-46-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 3.13.0-46-generic
Done.

wl:
Running module version sanity check.
- Original module
- No original module exists within this kernel
- Installation
- Installing to /lib/modules/3.13.0-46-generic/updates/dkms/
depmod.........

DKMS: install completed.
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Обрабатываются триггеры для initramfs-tools (0.103ubuntu4.2) …
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-46-generic
```

Comment: Did you compile the driver from source code or install it with Synaptic or apt-get?

Comment: @chili555 Installed via Synaptic. It is even availible in official repos

Answer (score 1):

To get the module to load automatically on boot, it is not necessary to amend *dkms*. Please open a terminal and do:

```
sudo -i
modprobe wl
depmod -a
echo wl  >>  /etc/modules
exit
```

You should be all set.

Comment: Thanks! I need to do it once and every kernel update wifi will be loaded? I've updated question. Is adding to DKMS complicated process?

Comment: This will load the driver at boot, not rebuild (recompile) it when there is a kernel update. The OP is right --- he or she has to add id to DKMS. Unfortunately, I have no idea on how to do it. As ever, you can probably learn it using the excellent Arch docs: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dynamic_Kernel_Module_Support

Comment: @Rmano The original was not compiled from source code so there is nothing to recompile. It was installed as a .deb from the official repositories and doesn't ever need to be recompiled or rebuilt. The answer I've given needs to be done just once.

Comment: OK. I was supposing a compilation giving the `building` messages, but probably the .deb itself did the correct dkms registering. Thanks.

Comment: @yanpas You needn't do anything more than what I suggest in my answer.